# How to generate table tr from multiple overlapping ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

While replacing legacy javascript with angularjs code, I'm stuck with the following use case (simplified code as follows):

```
<tr ng-repeat="section in page.sections>
   <td>{{section.name}}:</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="task in section.tasks>
   <td>{{task.name}}:</td>
</tr>
```

The expected result should be a single table, with task rows should follow parent section row.

I understand that the inner loop won't work because of the scope of the section element is not the parent of the inner loop.

Is there a work around (or a best suitable way) to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="section in page.sections">
    <td>{{section.name}}:</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="task in section.tasks">
    <td>{{task.name}}:</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="false" ng-repeat-end><td>end</td></tr>
```

See a [demo plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UdmwUBwu5YL99OCR5b7O?p=preview)